# How can I get more detailed error information in Bootstrap's make?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, makefile, less, twitter-recess

I'm new to using LESS, and to Bootstrap, and I'm building a site for fun.  When I run `make` in my `bootstrap` directory, if I screwed something up in my `variables.less` file I get a totally useless error message:

```
##################################################
Building Bootstrap...
##################################################

Running JSHint on javascript...             ✔ Done

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/lib/less/parser.js:385
                        throw new(LessError)(e, env);

[object Object]
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

How can I get some line numbers or something?  It wasn't too bad to figure out what was going on in this case (I misused `lighten(@color, 15%)`) but if I start hacking the design quite a bit as desired I feel like I'm going to run in to trouble, being a LESS newb and all.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running *lessc* directly?  It has a `--verbose` flag that might be helpful.  I don't know if *recess* has an equivalent.

Comment: There's an [outstanding issue about this on GitHub](https://github.com/twitter/recess/issues/73) which has a one-line fix* in the comments (*it replaces [object Object] with a more informative string, but it dumps a mini traceback)

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issues and I ran `lessc` directly (as merv suggested). I immediately had a context-sensitive error that I could deal with. Thanks, merv